# Where can i see which interface members to define when i'm using the interface?

Tags: c#, interface, abstract

Where can i see what members i have to implement when im using an interface in one of my classes?

When im using an abstract class, the intellisense would give me a lot of suggestions when im write "override", but how do i do it with interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of interface you MUST impliment all members.

when you have

```
class A:B{}
```

right click B

and you will have option on the context menu called "Impliment Abstract Interface"

Answer (score 1):

click on interface when implementing and press Crtl+. and you will see suggestion to implement members of interface and after that you should have all members implemented with sth like this:

```
public void Sth(string input)
{
     throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public class Implementing : ISomething <--here you need to press Ctrl+.
{
....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IntelliSense` which helps you implement an interface while working in the Code Editor or right click on the interface in the class definition and select option `Implement interface`